# How to find azure policy guest configuration details

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-policy

I have a virtual machine and I applied Azure policy for HITRUST/HIPAA to it. A couple of policies verified by the Azure Guest Configuration extension are not compliant. For example the policy *Windows machines should meet requirements for 'System Audit Policies - Account Management'* is using the guest configuration extension to validate vm's configuration. I know what should be set up on the vm to make it compliant with this policy but I want to find a definite source of information what is checked by this guest configuration.

A piece of configuration for this policy:

```
"guestConfiguration": {
    "name": "AzureBaseline_SystemAuditPoliciesAccountManagement",
    "version": "1.*"
}
```

How to find what is verified by AzureBaseline_SystemAuditPoliciesAccountManagement and other guest configuration checks.

Comment: Is the answer provided by kavyasaraboju-MT was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Guest Configuration policy definitions use the `AuditIfNotExists` effect. When the definition is assigned, a backend service automatically handles the lifecycle of all requirements in the `Microsoft.GuestConfiguration` Azure resource provider.
2. When an Azure Policy is assigned, if it's in the category "Guest Configuration" there's *metadata* included to describe a Guest Assignment. You can think of a Guest Assignment as a *link between a machine and an Azure Policy* scenario.
3. The following snippet associates the Azure Windows Baseline configuration with minimum version 1.0.0 to any machines in scope of the policy. By default, the Guest Assignment will only perform an audit of the machine.

   ```
   "metadata": {
       "category": "Guest Configuration",
       "guestConfiguration": {
           "name": "AzureWindowsBaseline",
           "version": "1.0"
       }
   ```

Please refer this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/guest-configuration#enable-guest-configuration